# JQuery - alert to display number of divs having a class but not another class

Tags: jquery

I have 8 divs. Each div has the class 'pre-loader'. In addition to thas class, six have the class 'loader'. Below those divs I have a button. When clicked I have an alert that is displaying the number of divs that have the class pre-loader and the class loader (6). What I would like, is that the alert displays the number of div that have the class 'pre-loader' but not the class 'loader' (2). Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

http://jsfiddle.net/XJukA/

my html:

```
<div class="pre-loader loader">text</div></br>
<div class="pre-loader loader">text</div></br>
<div class="pre-loader loader">text</div></br>
<div class="pre-loader loader">text</div></br>
<div class="pre-loader loader">text</div></br>
<div class="pre-loader loader">text</div></br>
<div class="pre-loader">text</div></br>
<div class="pre-loader">text</div></br>
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="click">​
```

my js:

```
$(document).on({
    click: function() {    

        alert($('.pre-loader.loader').length);

        }               
}, "#btn");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the :not selector

```
alert($('.pre-loader:not(.loader)').length);
```

Hope this helps

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's .not() function

```
$(document).on({
click: function() {    

    alert($('.pre-loader').not('.loader').length);

    }               
}, "#btn");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XJukA/3/

Comment: Hello Simon. Thanks. Your code is working but the one proposed by Richard also, and I will rather go with the syntax he proposes. Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(document).on({
    click: function() {    

        alert($('.pre-loader').not('.loader').length);

        }               
}, "#btn");
```